# Updating ComboBox selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm

I have a `ComboBox` that is that is being populated from an `ItemsSource` collection. I am populating all the customers into an Observable Collection, and binding it to the collection, like so.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Customers}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding CustomerKey}"
          DisplayMemberPath="FullName" SelectedValuePath="{Binding Key}" />
```

In this same view, I have a data grid with basic information with orders in it. When an order is selected, within the view model I am getting a more detailed record for the order. What I want to do is update the view with customer information for the newly selected order.

I was trying to set the `CustomerKey`, and then selected that Customer based on it's key -- I think I am doing this all wrong though. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Please also post your code where you set CustomerKey, and explain what goes wrong when you do it. Also the code where you have defined CustomerKey might help

Comment: Probably all you need to do is to change your code to `SelectedValuePath="Key"` (drop the binding) - this property is used in the same manner as `DisplayMemberPath`, which you used correctly.

Comment: I guess that'll be more easy to use `SelectedIndex` of ComboBox and get selected customer directly from `Customers` collection, when binded value will change, and there you could do what ever you want with Customer. Other way you could use `Customer` itself via `SelectedItem={Binding SelectedCustomer}`

Comment: You are doing this the hard way.  In every ItemsControl, you want to only bind to ItemsSource and SelectedItem.  And, really, to be completely simple you should not be getting "a more detailed record of the order", your ItemsSource should be bound to a collection of these detailed records.  The  only reason you would not want to do this is if getting those detailed records is too expensive.  And I mean *really* too expensive.  Not "I think" too expensive.  Measured and is unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

The SelectedValuePath property of the ComboBox should be set to a *string* (and not to a binding) that specifies the name of the property of the Customer class where the key is stored:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Customers}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding CustomerKey}"
          DisplayMemberPath="FullName" SelectedValuePath="Key" />
```

This will work provided that the Customer class has a FullName and a Key property and that the Key property has the same type as the CustomerKey property of the view model.

A customer with a key matching the value that you set the CustomerKey property to must also be present in the Customers collection that you bind the ComboBox to for an item to be selected.